# How would you use a variable which is defined below your function?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I am trying to make a calculator using classes but I get error as "variable not defined"

What I am trying is (there are more functions in my codes, but the related code is)

```
def Start():
    x = input("Please input what you want do to a number then the number; a whole number.\n(Example pi 2)\nYou can pow (pow 2 3; 2 to the power of 3),pi,square and cube: ").lower()
    x = x.split()
    Action = x[0]
    number = int(x[1])
    print ("Your number: " + str(number))

class Cal:
    def pi():
        print ("Your number multiplied by Pi: " + str(math.pi * number))

def Again():
    y = input("Type 'Yes' to do another one if not type 'No': ").lower()

    if "yes" in y:
        print ("\n")
        Start()
        Work()
        Again()
    elif "no" in y:
        pass

def Work():
    if Action.startswith("pi"):
        Cal.pi()
    else:
        pass

Start()
Work()
Again()
```

I am getting "Variable not defined only"
I am using Windows 7 and Python 3.3. What could be the possible issue?

Comment: Which variable usage is not defined?

Comment: To peoples downvoting this question: we all were newbies one day, and at least the op tried something. Please keep your downvotes for those that ask for ready-made answers to their assignements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitely pass your "variables" to the functions that need them. You can read more about this in any programming tutorial (starting with Python's official tutorial). To "get" the variables from the function that sets them you have to `return` the variable(s). That's really CS101 BTW

As an exemple:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
   print arg1, arg2

def bar():
   y = raw_input("y please")
   return y

what = "Hello"
whatelse = bar()
foo(what, whatelse)
```

More on this here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Fixed version of your script (nb tested on Python 2.7 with a hack for `input` but should work as is on 3.x):

```
import math

def Start():
    x = input("Please input what you want do to a number then the number; a whole number.\n(Example pi 2)\nYou can pow (pow 2 3; 2 to the power of 3),pi,square and cube: ").lower()
    x = x.split()
    Action = x[0]
    number = int(x[1])
    print ("Your number: " + str(number))
    return (Action, number)


class Cal:
    def pi(self, number):
        print ("Your number multiplied by Pi: " + str(math.pi * number))

def Again():
    y = input("Type 'Yes' to do another one if not type 'No': ").lower()

    if "yes" in y:
        print ("\n")
        args = Start()
        Work(*args)
        Again()
    elif "no" in y:
        pass

def Work(Action, *args):
    if Action.startswith("pi"):
        Cal().pi(*args)
    else:
        pass

def Main():
    args = Start()
    Work(*args)
    Again()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: So if I wanted to add more fuctinons to Cal all I would have to do is just put def cube(self, number): to start it.

Comment: `def <wathever>(...)` _defines_ a function. Then you have to call it - like you did for `pi()`. BTW you had another couple errors there (that I fixed but won't explain), and you really don't need a class here. If you're still fighting with basic concepts like arguments, return values and loops, no need to use classes for now.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `Start()` function, put

```
global Action
```

That way, the variable will enter the global scope, so it will be visible from the other functions.

However, this is not good style. Rather, you should pass parameters to other functions instead of relying on global variables.

Comment: A global variable is not a good idea. It breaks the idea of modularity. I would make sure you pass in the variables you want to use. I really don't think you should be calling that variable Again but if you want to, making it global is not the best way.

Comment: Could someone make a example of how you would do it?

Comment: Adding `global` before a name doesn't make the name visible from other functions.